# JavaScript code to remove item from array goes wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove items from an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < transformedColumns.length; i++) {
  if (data[0].indexOf(transformedColumns[i] > -1)) {                   
       delete transformedColumns[i];
  }
}
```

The thing I'm doing Is to check if the value in transformedColumns[i] exists in data[0] array. If It does, the value should be removed from the transformedColumns.

But when I do like above, the whole transformedColumns becomes undefined.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < transformedColumns.length; i++) {
        if (data[0].indexOf(transformedColumns[i] > -1)) {                   
            transformedColumns.splice(transformedColumns[i], 1);
        }
    }
```

This works, except that it removes a value from transformedColumns that does not exist in data[0]. Let's say that transformedColumns contains ["Item No", "Item Name", "Item State"] and data[0] contains ["Item No", Item Name"]. The only values that should be removed from transformedColumnes are Item No and Item Name, not Item State.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete): _"The `delete` operator removes a **property from an object**"_, [`Array.prototype.splice(start, deleteCount)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice): _"`start` : **Index** at which to start changing the array"_, _"`deleteCount`: An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data[0].indexOf(transformedColumns[i] > -1)
```

You having wrong condition statement. your condition should be

```
(data[0].indexOf(transformedColumns[i]) >-1 )
```

You are passing a condition to indexOf which fails

```
indexOf(transformedColumns[i] > -1)
```

That is the reason it is returning true for all the cases. Should work after you fix that

```
 for (var i = 0; i < transformedColumns.length; i++) {
        if (data[0].indexOf(transformedColumns[i]) > -1 ) {                   
            transformedColumns.splice(transformedColumns[i], 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is more advisable. Use `splice` instead of `delete` since `delete` will results in vacant space inside array.

Comment: `.splice(transformedColumns[i], 1)` is still wrong. The first parameter of `.splice()` is an index and not a string.